# Fantasy Book with color coded districts and underground school

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find a book that a friend read when she was at school but can't remember the name.  It has an underground school and they can travel to different worlds. There were different districts that were colour coded.  She thinks it had an orange cover. she would have read this in the 2000's.   Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be the seventh tower series?

[image: book cover for "the fall"]

The world is shrouded by a veil casting it all into darkness, so it come across as underground. The book is set in a castle inhabited by people who do magic with light - the colour of light used denotes the power of the magic. Districts get assigned colours according to the colour of the magic of those living there. The magic is done with glowing stones taken from another world - which people in the castle can cross to.

Answer (score 2):

Could it have been the Myst Reader? Involved underground, traveling to different worlds, I'm not remembering color coding even though it might be involved in some way. It's been over a decade since I picked it up.

[image: The Myst Reader]

Comment: There was no color coding at all in any of those three novels.  *Book of Ti'ana* featured an underground city / civilization, not just a school, while the other two had some plot portions in the ruins of that same city.  Only what you have pictured here & *Book of Atrus* was released with brown/orange cover.  You've got some hits, but it doesn't seem to fit as a whole.

Comment: @RebeccaTitheridge And is it?